Bad version of the SoLoader SDK causing crashes on 64-bit devices - Error on Play Console during app review
I'm experiencing an issue outdated version of the SoLoader SDK. The error message suggests updating the SoLoader SDK to version 0.10.4 or higher. Below are the details of the issue and what I've tried to resolve it.
Issue Details:
My app uses React Native version 0.58.8.
I'm encountering an error related to the SoLoader SDK version, which states:
"Bad version of the SoLoader SDK. Your app uses a version of the SoLoader SDK that can cause crashes on 64 bit-only devices. To resolve this, update the SoLoader SDK to version 0.10.4 or higher."
What I Have Tried:
Attempted to Update SoLoader:
Updated the SoLoader SDK to version 0.10.5 by modifying the build.gradle file and specifying the updated version.
Checked the version of SoLoader in node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/gradle.properties file:-
SO_LOADER_VERSION=0.10.5

Tried Cache Clean and Invalidate Caches:
Cleared the cache and invalidated caches in Android Studio, but the issue persists.
Tried the Following Steps but They Didn't Work:
Ran ./gradlew app:dependencies to check for multiple versions of SoLoader.
Ensured no multiple versions of SoLoader exist in the project.
Forced the newer version of SoLoader by adding configuration in build.gradle.
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.soloader') {
            details.useVersion "0.10.5"
        }
    }
}


Clean and Rebuild the Project:
Ran the following commands:
./gradlew clean
./gradlew build


Check for Transitive Dependencies:
Forced the correct version using:
implementation ('com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5') { force = true }


Ensure Correct Architecture Support:-
Verified the APK/AAB supports 64-bit architecture
Questions:
How can I update the SoLoader SDK to version 0.10.4 or higher without breaking compatibility with React Native 0.58.8?
Are there specific steps or configurations needed to make SoLoader 0.10.4+ work with my version of React Native?
Is there a workaround for this issue without upgrading React Native?

Is there a reason why you don't use the recent version 0.11.0?

React Native is at version 0.75 ...while version 0.58 is already archived. One can even provide SoLoader as module: https://github.com/facebook/SoLoader?tab=readme-ov-file#building-from-source

I have attempted to use versions 0.10.4, 0.10.5, and 0.11+, but I am still encountering an error when uploading a new build. Despite these attempts, the store is still tracking the previous error. Could you please provide assistance or further guidance on resolving this issue?

I had the same issue with React Native 0.66.4.
What worked for me is changing the android/build.gradle as follows:
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
            [...]
            force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4"
        }
    }
    [...]
}

Unfortunately, simply ignoring the warning in the Play Store Console did not work because the app is crashing at times.
I hope this helps!

Issue on React native 0.66.0
Add this block in android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4"
    }
}


This is what worked for me:

in file android/build.gradle, added inside ext block:
soLoaderVersion = "0.10.4+"

in file android/app/build.gradle, added inside dependencies block:
implementation "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:$soLoaderVersion"


credit: https://medium.com/@enginergen/react-native-application-freezes-crashes-samsung-galaxy-s24-devices-7620ad42aa16

This is the version that did it for me
android/app/build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4"
}

Potentially these steps might be needed
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npm install
npx react-native run-android
and for the forced approach suggestion was
dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4") {
        force = true
    }
}

